# Add tag synonyms for [cloudfront] & [amazon-cloud-front] -> [amazon-cloudfront] on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

**Synonym-Request:** I noticed there already is a synonym relation among [cloudfront](/questions/tagged/cloudfront) and [amazon-cloud-front](/questions/tagged/amazon-cloud-front). Yet there are also several questions tagged [amazon-cloudfront](/questions/tagged/amazon-cloudfront).

Considering the official variant » **[Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/)** « can the proper tag synonym relations be created among the three of them?